# LDR polarity DOES matter?

Tags: arduino, ldr

Today is one of the strangest problems with a circuit I just run into.

[image: 111]

This is my basic circuit except I use barebone Atmega 328P on 5V and the sensor reading (analog read integer value 0-1023) is sent by a 433mhz transmitter to another node.

After assembling my circuit today I have noticed a weird behavior I cannot explain. Whenever the LDR was connected the radio sent no data at all or there might be another issue I don't know about running the code but if the LDR was not connected (the analog pin float) then it was working. I got values close to 0 and even if I sorted out the LDR input pins the max value 1023 was transmitted but if the LDR was connected the circuit did not respond.

After trying everything possible including connecting a brand new LDR to the same place I have noticed that with a certain polarity it works.
I have checked both the old and new LDRs (have high resistance like 60k in dark, goes to 10k range in light), they behaved exactly the same with the multimeter.

I can reproduce this issue with both LDRs any time. So are LDRs have some sort of polarity for real or do they act as a diode?

Comment: Data sheet for this 'LDR'?

Comment: what about presenting a schematic rather than some doodling?

Comment: This unclearly described behavior could just as easily be a software problem as a hardware one, you will need to include your code.

Comment: A lot of bla bla then you **think** it has something to do with the LDR and you focus on that. Instead of pointing at something random (the LDR) you need to learn how to do proper fault analysis. Start with something simple like reading out the voltage from the LDR circuit through the serial interface. When that works, reverse the LDR. If the result is different (it will not be) then you have the answer to your question. Does that solve the system not working ? Nope.

Answer (score 1):

You are now in the debug phase of your little project. There are two parts to it which can be debugged separately.

1. Using a multimeter connected to GND, measure the voltage on the analog input. This should be somewhere in the middle between 0 and 5 V and should vary with light level.
2. If that's OK but readings are wrong: check that your code is configuring the input as an analog in and not a digital input.
3. If that's OK then try replacing the LDR with another 10k resistor to give 2.5 V in. Your ADC reading should now be 1024/2 = 500 approx.

Use the serial print function to monitor the ADC readings via USB on your computer.

Report back.

Comment: Indeed - the serial output is key to verifying the local reading circuit, before worrying about the radio communication.

Answer (score 0):

Break this down into segments and start troubleshooting.

1. Is the voltage as expected on the analog input pin ?
2. Have your microcontroller output the ADC reading to serial monitor, log it or somehow display it, LCD, 8 segment display etc.
3. Start troubleshooting your radio modules to ensure they work
4. Then start testing transmitting the ADC value.

and so on.

It would be more helpful to have an actual schematic and part no. for the LDR.

Your code and radio though are huge question marks and seems to be more likely the issue is there somewhere